# How do I make pip or easy_install use /opt/python2.6/include?

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

I have built and installed python2.6.2 in /opt according to these instructions: http://casualengineer.blogspot.com/2009/09/install-python-262-on-centos-53.html#comment-form
but for some reason my pip and easy install can't find /opt/python2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h

How do I tell these utils where to find the 2.6 header files?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with pip or easy install but my guess is that /opt/python2.6/include is not hardcoded in those two app installers. It probably just searches /usr/include and /usr/local/include. Try creating an alias to the python2.6 directory in /usr/include or something like that or check the flags for ./configure on those apps. You might be able to specify a directory.